# Half part of debug banner hiding! Why?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have tried everything which came in my mind to solve this issue but couldn't
**This is troubling me because when I try to navigate to other screen That white portion on the top of the screen gets carried forward and gives it an awkward look**

[image: Screenshot]

I am calling the following screen from main.dart:-

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(child: IntroScrn.screens(context),)
    );
  }
}
```

and the actual class is here :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nice_intro/intro_screen.dart';
import 'package:nice_intro/intro_screens.dart';

class IntroScrn extends StatefulWidget {

  static IntroScreens screens(BuildContext context) {
    return IntroScreens(
      onDone: () => Navigator.of(context)
          .popAndPushNamed('/screen1'),
      onSkip: () => Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CategoryList())),
      footerBgColor: Color(0xff262335),
      activeDotColor: Colors.white,
      footerRadius: 170.0,

//      indicatorType: IndicatorType.CIRCLE,
      slides: [
        IntroScreen(
          title: 'Wohh!',
          headerPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          imageAsset: 'assets/img/1.png',
          description: 'Quickly find all vegetables at glance',
          headerBgColor: Colors.white,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  _IntroScrnState createState() => _IntroScrnState();
}

class _IntroScrnState extends State<IntroScrn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: @Niteesh Have added the code too !

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER VERSION 2.0**

In your `MyHomePageState`, declare `extendBodyBehindAppBar`, this would some how hide the app bar. I guess the white screen is nothing but your appbar which is being shown somehow.

1. Check whether `appbar` is declared in any of the `Scaffold`
2. If not, then just declare `extendBodyBehindAppBar` to `true`, this will make the child overlap the appbar, if somehow exists

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  body: Container(child: IntroScrn.screens(context),) 
)
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

If that doesn't work out then, try declaring the appbar, and make it transparent in same `MyHomePageState`

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appbar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0
  ),
  body: Container(child: IntroScrn.screens(context),) 
)
```

Let me know if that works out for you.

**BTW - LIKED YOUR UI** Good job on that

Comment: No it didn't give the solution to my question which is written above the image in bold on the top

Comment: Why do you need the Debug Banner anyway, when you can hide it in your app @Hari?

Comment: actually , This is troubling me because when I try to navigate to other screen That white portion on the top of the screen (which is hiding debug banner) gets carried forward and gives it an awkward look

Comment: @Hari, I have updated the answer, let me know, if that works for you asap, so that we can check for some other solutions, if that doesn't work out

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue I added a line to resolve the issue:-

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0),child: AppBar(title:Text(""),backgroundColor:Colors.white,elevation: 0,)),
        body: Container(child: IntroScrn.screens(context),)
    );
  }
}
```

And Boom! my problem just went away!

Comment: Hey Hari, didn't any  of my solutions work out for you?

Comment: @Alok no they didn't but anyways thanks to help me out 

Comment: Oh, is it? Usually I use this work out my stuffs. But anyways, glad that you found out the solution :)